# Добавить отступы для рекурсивного парсера

Tags: python, lxml, python-3.x

помогите пожалуйста добавить отступы, соответствующие уровню вложенности

привожу код, в котором при выводе на экран элементы верхнего(первого) уровня не имеют отступа. элементы второго уровня имеют отступ(1 символ табуляции). если появятся элементы третьего уровня, то они тоже будут иметь отступ величиной в 1 символ табуляции. а надо чтобы у них отступ был в 2 символа табуляции. как это реализовать я не представляю

```
import pprint
import requests
import lxml.etree
import lxml.html

def get_catalog(url):
    req = requests.get(url)
    html = req.text
    doc = lxml.html.document_fromstring(html)
    listCatalog = doc.xpath('//section[@class="catalog"]/ul')
    return listCatalog

def parse_ul(listUl, indent=''):
    for elemUL in listUl:
        listLI = elemUL.xpath('li')
        if listLI:
            for elemLI in listLI:
                nameCat = elemLI.xpath('a/text()')[0].strip()
                print(indent, nameCat)             
                newUL = elemLI.xpath('ul')
                if newUL:
                    parse_ul(newUL, indent='\t')

listCatalog = get_catalog('http://first-store.ru/')
parse_ul(listCatalog)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

попробуйте так

```
def parse_ul(listUl, level=0):
    for elemUL in listUl:
        listLI = elemUL.xpath('li')
        if listLI:
            for elemLI in listLI:
                nameCat = elemLI.xpath('a/text()')[0].strip()

                print(u"%s%s" % (level * ' ', nameCat))

                newUL = elemLI.xpath('ul')
                if newUL:
                    parse_ul(newUL, level=level+1)
```

но в вашем примере нет елементов 3го уровня вложенности

Comment: я так пробовал в первую очередь. получается "горка" потому что почти при каждой итерации размер отступа только увеличивается. то есть он не уменьшается вообще никогда

Comment: Нет, горки не получается. Все работает как нужно.
Прошу убедится лично:

https://gist.github.com/LinnTroll/d6522f1f92a66338c7a5

ветки iPhone/iPhone 5 и iPhone/iPhone 4/4s

Comment: извиняюсь. действительно работает